# SwiftのSKLabelNodeで独自フォントを表示したい

Tags: swift

将棋の駒を表示したく下記のコードを GameSceneクラスに記述しました。

```
    let king = SKLabelNode()
    king.fontName = "KsShogiPieces"
    king.text = "A";
    king.fontColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    king.fontSize = 45;
    king.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:300);

    self.addChild(king)
```

結果が下記の画像なのですが、ttfファイル(http://ksbookshelf.com/FD/KsShogiPieces.htm　からダウンロード）
を入れて、Info.plistのFont Provided by applicationにも追加していますが、
ラベルで表示されるのは**A**になります。(王将の対応文字はAでした。)

インポートしたフォントをSKLabelNodeで使用するには
どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: フォント名に`"K's Japanese Shogi Pieces"`を指定してみてください。

Comment: うまくいきました！
ttfファイルの名前ではないんですね。